# What are the key technical challenges to development of traveling wave reactors?

Tags: energy, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology, nuclear-reprocessing

I recently learned about traveling wave reactors (TWRs) on the [Netflix Bill Gates special](https://www.netflix.com/title/80184771), as an example of a cutting-edge technology Gates is funding which has the potential solve several environmental problems.

The TWR is a nuclear fission reactor which sounds a *bit* too good to be true (via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_wave_reactor)):

- Uses spent fuel from other fission reactors, meaning it doesn't require mining of new uranium
- *Consumes* the spent fuel from these reactors, meaning it could be used to dispose of this nuclear waste
- Doesn't produce any of its own toxic byproducts
- Can run in containment for decades, with no need to add/remove fuel, reducing operational costs and risk to operators

So, what gives? **Why don't these exist yet?** The Wikipedia article (and the Netflix special) mention some political challenges that have delayed construction of a demonstration reactor, but I wasn't able to find any additional detail on technical challenges.

Like fusion reactors (which have both political and financial support, and never seem to get any closer to existing), I assume there must be some specific, unsolved technical challenges.

Comment: Bill Gates, which has tirelessly been working on advancing this to generate cheap power for poor communities had a contract with China to build a small scale working prototype. But Trump has basically torpedoed the project.

Comment: [This](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2019/ph241/wulff1/) Stanford coursework references a few scientific articles in peer-reviewed journals. The problem seems to be that most of the research is published by TerraPower themselves.

Comment: I'm particularly interested to which degree the technology depends on non-renewal resource inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any technological challenges.  There have been several sodium fast reactors that have operated, the latest being the Experimental Breeder Reactor II (EBR-II) in Idaho and the Fast Flux Test Facility (FFTF) in Washington.  The next step in the development is to build one and gain operational experience.

I think the answer you are looking for is "cost".  These reactors will be first-of-a-kind builds and will be expensive, much more expensive alternative methods of generating electricity.  The only realistic way for one to be built is if the government funds it as a research project, and it just isn't a high priority right now.

For it to be a higher priority, it needs to solve an urgent problem.  There are currently cheaper ways to generate electricity, so this isn't a driver.  Uranium is cheap right now, so there isn't a need to develop a breeder reactor.  People talk about nuclear waste, but the reality is that it is accumulating at reactor sites without any major issues.

I personally would love to see one built, but there isn't currently a driver for spending the money.